# Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type '(key: String)'

Tags: xcode, swift3, swift2

Can someone help me with the following error ? I made a migration from swift 2 to swift 3 and in my code it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type '(key: String)'
```

and

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type '(index: Int)'
```

My code:

```
fileprivate subscript(sub: SubscriptType) -> JSON {
        get {
            if sub is String {
                return self[key:sub as! String]
            } else {
                return self[index:sub as! Int]
            }
        }
        set {
            if sub is String {
                self[key:sub as! String] = newValue
            } else {
                self[index:sub as! Int] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using a Swift 3 compatible version of SwiftyJSON?

Comment: I will try to use SwiftyJSON, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove key: and index: from your code, i think will resolve.

ex: self[sub as! String]